# <BIMServer - EMF> Custom IFC Schema (IdObject to EObject

Tags: java, emf, ifc

I'm trying to extend `IFC` schema with custom entities and relationships. So far, what I have done, is:

Use JSDAI to extend, in EXPRESS-G, IFC4 schema.
With the new schema, generate .ecore (using EMF) and after that, using .genmodel, generate Java classes.

Using `BIMServer` classes, I'm able (of course) to read `IFC4` files but what I want to do is:

a) `REad IFC` file

b) Add to `IfcModel` my new entities

c) GEnerate a new `IFC` file (`.ifc`) with my new entities (I suppose I have to implement a new `IfcSerializer`).

The problem is at point b), because `IfcDeserializer` gives elements/entities as `IdEObject` and my java classes generated by `EMF` extend from `EObject`.

Supposedly I have to transform `IdEObject (IFC4)` to `EObject (IFC4Custom)` and after that implements a serializer to generate from `EOBjects` a `IFC` file.

Honestly, I'm a little bit lost..

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  You can take the [tour] first and learn [ask] a good question and create a [mcve].  That makes it easier for us to help you.

Comment: Hello @Angel Ruiz, were you able to solve your problem? I'm very interested in the solution. Thanks!